# how to construct zero cross detecting circuit for line current?

Tags: current, resistors, opto-isolator, zero-crossing

I am constructing Optocoupler based Zero cross detection circuit for power factor correction.How to find zero crossing of current wave?please recommend the circuits with resistor calculations.

thankyou

Comment: Please show that you have done some [research](https://www.google.ie/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1378&bih=834&q=Optocoupler+based+Zero+cross+detection&oq=Optocoupler+based+Zero+cross+detection&gws_rd=cr&ei=JmNLWeb_MOWHgAafnKGQCQ) and then ask for help on something you don't understand. This is not a free design service.

Comment: Convert current to voltage, repeat the zero crossing circuit.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: will send you the worked out circuit

Answer (score 1):

To measure current, use a CT (current transformer) - this converts the current taken by a load or appliance into an isolated and manageable signal voltage that is proportional to load current but, beware, if your currents are not sinusoidal, then trying to compare the zero crossing point of voltage and current is going to be a big problem. Consider an appliance such as a TV or HiFi and look at the typical current taken: -

[image]

With these sorts of appliances (and many others too), the current drawn from the AC line comes in very non-sinusoidal blips coincident with the recharging of a reservoir capacitor after the bridge rectifier.

If you were to take a zero-cross point of the current waveform, where would that be in the picture above? In other words, for many household and some industrial loads, you can't use zero-cross detectors to give any indication of the relative phase angle between voltage and current.

Simultaneously sample v and i at a fast rate such as 1 kHz minimum, then multiply and average to get power taken. Also compute Vrms and Irms and compute power factor of load using: -

PF = \$\dfrac{Power}{V_{RMS}\times I_{RMS}}\$

See [**this**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76213/how-to-sense-the-zero-crossing-of-current) Q&A for further information. Ditto [**this**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202667/whats-the-most-economical-way-to-digitally-measure-240v-mains-voltage-current) answer too.